# processing: several circles into each other + changing color

Tags: java, while-loop, geometry, processing

I have to do smth. like this and I can't figure out what the problem is.
Here is my code:

```
size(200,200);
background(255);
float w = 200 ;
float radius = 20;
while ( radius <= 200) {
    stroke(0);
    fill( w );
    ellipse( 100 , 100 , radius, radius);
    w -= 10;
    radius += 20;
}
```

it should look like this:

[image]

Comment: About tag `circle`: "This tag has been deprecated. Please use [geometry] instead." I will edit that for you, but please next time read the tag-wiki! Moreover, I suggest you include one more tag, which specifies the language you are using... ;)

Comment: In the future, please explain what you expected your code to do, what it does instead, and what you think the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set "fill" color with an alpha channel. If you call [`fill()`](https://processing.org/reference/fill_.html) with 1 parameter, then only the gray color is set. Use 2 parameters, to set the gray color and the alpha channel.

```java
fill( w, w );
```

Since the default belnd mode is [`BLEND`](https://processing.org/reference/blendMode_.html), the objects are blendend. This means, if more objects are drawn at the same place, then the scene will become more saturated at this parts. So it is not necessary to consecutively change `w`.

```java
size(200,200);
background(255);
float w = 60;
float radius = 20;
while ( radius <= 200) {
    stroke(0);
    fill( w, w );
    ellipse(100, 100, radius, radius);
    radius += 20;
}
```

Preview:

[image]